# Declare NSString in .h file - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may sound like a silly question, but I can'f find easily any solution online.

How to declare a NSString in .h file?

I have tried this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *DATABASE_NAME;
```

but I get an error:

> Expected member name or ';' after declaration

What's the problem here?

**EDIT**

My header file:

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

    @property BOOL MAP_SATELLITE_VIEW;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *DATABASE_NAME;

+ (GlobalVariables*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Comment: With ARC we'd use `strong` instead of `retain`, but I think that you have an issue elsewhere. Before or after. If you comment/remove that line do you still have an issue? Where did you put that line exactly? Could you share the whole .h file?

Comment: I don't have any issues if I remove that line.

Comment: Yeap, that was the problem. I have defined it somewhere else. If you want, write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Student try https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you show, so you must look in its context. Some ideas:

- Check how/where `#import` the `.h` file.
- Check if `DATABASE_NAME` been defined elsewhere.
- What happens if you replace this line with something else, for example: `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger dummyInt;`, or add this above that line?

Comment: Thanks for you time.